# Relative paths in HTML from `filesDir` won't work

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to load html from `filesDir` using `webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, htmlString)`. The **relative paths** in the HTML won't work hence it loads without styles, javascript and images.

The `baseUrl` that I am providing is `file:///data/user/0/com.mydomain.app/files/folder/index.html` The issue gets resolved when the `baseUrl` is changed to `file:///android_asset/folder/index.html`.

Note : Currently the assets are present in both `android_asset` as well as `filesDir` folders; but I am planning to remove the assets from `android_asset` folder.

##### In App file structure

```kotlin
main
  assets
    folder
      index.html
    utils
      style.css
      script.js
    images
      image.jpg
  java
  res
```

##### `filesDir` (Persistant Files) structure

```
com.mydomain.app
  cache
  files
    folder
      index.html
    utils
      style.css
      script.js
    images
      image.jpg
```

Content of index.html is passed as `htmlString`.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../utils/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <img src="../images/image.jpg"/>
  <script src="../utils/script.css" />
</body>
```

Comment: `The relative paths in the HTML won't work` We cannot see what you do. Please post a minimal `htmlString`.

Comment: I've added the `htmlString`. It is nothing but content of index.html

Comment: If getFilesDir() does not work with ../ then put the css and js and image files in same directory as html or put images and utils directory in folder directory and get rid of ../.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to call `setAllowFileAccess` in `WebSettings` to enable access to `file://` URLs, as they're disabled by default in API 30 and above.

```
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Your solutions seems to be working for everything except `glb` models in `<model-viewer>`. The issue is related to CORS (which I have no idea about). But I think, that is a topic that deserves its own question.